# Default initializer in protocol

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I would like to specify a default implementation for an initializer in a protocol, so that I can run code on all structs conforming to a specific protocol.

I have the following example:

```swift
protocol ProtWithInit {
    init()
}

extension ProtWithInit {
    init() {
        self.init()
        print("Hello protocol")
    }
}

struct MyStruct {}

extension MyStruct: ProtWithInit {}

let myStruct = MyStruct()
```

What I would like the `MyStruct()` call to do, is output "Hello protocol". However, nothing is being outputted when I run the above code.

Additionally, I would like to add to the initializer in the struct. So for example in the struct I add `print("Hello struct")` to the initializer and this would then outut both `hello protocol` and `hello struct`.

Is there any way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This, if it did anything, would be an infinite loop:

```
extension ProtWithInit {
    init() {
        self.init()
        print("Hello protocol")
    }
}
```

Structs and protocols are not classes. They do not have class-like inheritance. (Even if this were a class, this would be an infinite loop, since `self.init()` would just call `init()` again.)

Go back to your calling code, the code you say "so that I can run code on all structs conforming to a specific protocol." What do *that* code look like. What does it actually require on real types? Use that to work out your protocol. For example, the following would be similar to what you're describing:

```
extension ProtWithInit {
    static func create() -> Self {
        print("Hello protocol")
        return Self.init()
    }
}

let myStruct = MyStruct.create()
```